# "Can to do" in song's lyrics

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, infinitives, bare-infinitive

In the song "The next right thing" from the Frozen 2 soundtrack there is a strange part in the lyrics:

```
Take a step, step again
It is all that I can to do
The next right thing
```

Why "can to do", is it even grammatical? It there some sort of special meaning or "feel" to it?
And it is not required by the melody, I mean, it could very well do without this extra syllable, so I'm assuming it was put there on purpose.

Comment: You need to parse it:  It's all that I can / to do the next right thing.

Comment: By inserting a comma here after 'can', it should be meaningful. "Take a step, step again
It is all that I can, to do
The next right thing

Comment: @Hot Licks It's an extremely 'literary' usage. But then _lyrics_, I suppose.